# Select cells instead of a row in a swt table

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I have a SWT table. When I click, I don't want to select a full row, but certain cells. Is that possible?

My current code is:

```
tableViewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.NONE);
    Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    this.tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(
            new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1));
    TableLayout layout = new TableLayout();
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, 20, true));
    layout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(20, 20, true));
    this.tableViewer.getTable().setLayout(layout);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new ITableLabelProvider() {
               ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the [JFace Snippets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFaceSnippets), and search for "cell". There several useful snippets to pick from...

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation is that only cells are selected not rows. In your case whole rows are being selected because you have selected `fullSelection` to true.
Replace your code with this, it should work.

```
this.tableViewer.getTable().setLayoutData(
        new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the text of the cell you can use getCell()

```
this.tableViewer.getTable().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        ViewerCell viewerCell = this.tableViewer.getCell(new Point(e.x,e.y));
        String cellText = viewerCell.getText();
        System.out.println("Cell clicked: " + cellText);
    }
});
```